# Angular 4 doesnt display my components views

Tags: javascript, angular

Im learning to use Angular 4 and im not being able to render more than 1 template, my starting App template is OK, and it renders fine, but then i created 2 more components with "ng g component newComponent" and im not being able to make them display anything. I can type the new components URL in the browser and it navigates fine without errors, but it always displays the app.component.html My files are like this:

app.component.html

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<p>
  ASDASDASDAS
</p>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true }
    )
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

dashboard.component.html

```
<p>
  dashboard works!
</p>
```

dashboard.componentspec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

describe('DashboardComponent', () => {
  let component: DashboardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DashboardComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DashboardComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.less']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

My login component is similar, and my three components displays the same:

ASDASDASDAS

I dont know where my problem is, i have no error messages in any of the consoles. My project Structure is:

```
-src
--app
---dashboard
----dashboard.component.html
----dashboard.component.less
----dashboard.component.spec.ts
----dashboard.component.ts
---login
----login.component.html
----login.component.less
----login.component.spec.ts
----login.component.ts
--app.component.html
--app.component.less
--app.component.spec.ts
--app.component.ts
--app.module.ts
```

Do i need different NgModules for my purpose of totally separated views? I mean i want a page with "Login", another for "Dashboard", another for idk, a new page...etc, each one needs an NgModule for having separated views?

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Do you have the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your app.component.html?

Comment: No, could you point me how should app.component.html be built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` into `app.component.html` to define a place where other components will be rendered.

An example of `app.component.html` content:

```
<div class="app">
  <app-header></app-header>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

You can read more [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-outlet).